Running Inno Setup as a system account(Jenkins) to sign uninstaller
Description:

I installed Inno Setup 6.3.3 on my build server(Windows Server 2025).
Inno Setup will be called by Jenkins(as a Windows Service account).
Inno Setup will be needed to sign my installer and uninstaller.
The uninstaller is embedded in the installer, so to sign the uninstaller, we need to set up something

set a variable(mySignTool) to "Tools->configure Sign tools" with my signtool script.
add SignedUninstaller=yes under the [Setup]
add SignTool=mySignTool $f under the [Setup]



Then it keep report "Value of [Setup] section directive "SignTool" is invalid.".
I pretty sure the "SignTool" is valid, because I manually run it from command line, it will be working well. I did all the search on google and failed to find a valid solution.
After I found it maybe caused by the running account(LocalSystem), the only difference between I executed it from command line as Administrator.
After I downloaded the "PsExec" tool to run all the thing from System with "psexec -s cmd.exe", yes, it report "SignTool" is invalid also.
But under the LocalSystem account, with execute "signtool", is valid command.
(I hope the above can help someone).
Now I don't know how to make Inno Setup know "SignTool" when running as LocalSystem.
Or Leave the ".e32" file error in Jenkins script, and then Sign it with manual sign command?
